# Wrong Tax calculation in Magento on HHVM

Tags: magento, hhvm

I'm running Magento 1.9.1.0 at HHVM 3.14.4

I added `hhvm.enable_zend_sorting = 1` to /etc/hhvm/php.ini file and  /etc/hhvm/server.ini, but the tax calculation is actually wrong.
[Magento Wrong Tax Calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DTha.png)
34,90*0,07 = 2,429 and not 2,28 like Magento show it.

Has anyone an idea how I can solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I fixed it by patching app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml:

```
diff --git a/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml b/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml
index f32ac46..852865d 100644
--- a/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml
+++ b/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml
@@ -1218,7 +1218,7 @@
                     </subtotal>
                     <shipping>
                         <class>sales/quote_address_total_shipping</class>
-                        <after>subtotal,freeshipping,tax_subtotal</after>
+                        <after>subtotal,freeshipping,tax_subtotal,msrp</after>
                         <before>grand_total</before>
                     </shipping>
                     <grand_total>
@@ -1227,6 +1227,7 @@
                     </grand_total>
                     <msrp>
                         <class>sales/quote_address_total_msrp</class>
+                        <before>grand_total</before>
                     </msrp>
                 </totals>
                 <nominal_totals>
```

You might want to wrap it up as an extension to make it upgrade-proof.

here is an example of how to overwrite core config.xml https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10695/how-to-override-config-xml